# WPF 3D Rotation Point

Tags: wpf, 3d, rotation

I have a 3D object that I'm rotating in WPF.
I need to know how to move the point that the object is rotating on.  Currently my object rotates from the 0,0,0.  I'd like to be able to change the the point of rotation to 50,0,0 (or any other point I set).

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set the RotateTransform3D CenterX, CenterY, or CenterZ parameter to account for the offset where you want the rotation to happen.